# Cant find Gunicorn file in deployment for django app

Tags: python, mysql, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am following a guide about deployment of `django` application using `gunicorn` `mysql` and `nginx` without virtualenv.

Now the problem here is when installing the gunicorn using `pip install gunicorn` i cannot find where its installation directory. Im new on exploring `ubuntu os`.

I have searched and cant find anything where the gunicorn file resides.

---

Here is the [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04) link but it use virtualenv

Comment: Why do you think you need to know where the file is?

Comment: there is a command that need the file location of gunicorn sir

Comment: What command? I doubt there is any need to know the location of the file; if it's installed by pip it's on the path so that's all you need. Maybe you should show what guide you are following if you think it's telling you otherwise.

Comment: here it is  `exec myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application` the problem here is the guide is using virtualenv but i would like to do this without

Comment: `which gunicorn` shows path.

Comment: Big thanks to you @furas